# How to differentiate spotlights in a fragment shader?

Tags: three.js

Is it possible to distinguish somehow one spotlight from another in a fragment shader? For example, I created and added to the scene two spotlights A and B with the same characteristics. Now in the fragment shader I would like to determine if the current light is A or B while iterating over the `spotLights` array.

Comment: Why not just remembering using their index? If you know that A has index 0 and B has index 1

Comment: @Berthur Unfortunately I don't know much about three.js shaders and how to program them. In fragment shader I see accessing of `spotLights` array but what determines the order of elements in that array? Do you mean the array is filled in the same order as spotlights are added to the scene?

Comment: I think so. I haven't worked with Three.js lights in my shaders before so I don't know exactly where it takes the order from. But it should be easy enough to find out by trying, right? Also you have the position, color and other parameters you can use for identification.

Comment: Thank you! Of course, it won't be so hard to find out the order of lights from three.js sources. On the other hand, I was hoping there was a cleaner solution.

Comment: Lighting calculations in Three.js is an incredibly difficult topic if you don't know about shaders and how to program them. [here is a small part of the shader chunk](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/50bcb8d991269198cc0eca6ca0995b017b027ff0/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/lights_fragment_begin.glsl.js#L90-L103) where some of those calculations happen. You can see that it's an array-like loop, so light 0 goes first, light 1 goes second, etc...

Comment: @Marquizzo Yes, actually I used `lights_fragment_begin.glsl.js` chunk to create custom shader and it works well. But as you can see from my question I didn't see a way to reliably differentiate lights. For example, set light name in JS and then read that name in shader.